# Angular Nested CSS Div Table Alignment Issue

Tags: html, css, angular

I am trying to create my own tree table in Angular, however the problem I am having is that the columns are aligning improperly. I am able to successfully call a component recursively, but it displays in the wrong format. Essentially I have the following:

- Parent Component

  - Has Table Header Information
  - Calls row component (node of tree table)
- Node Component

  - Has table row information
  - Calls itself

Here is what that looks like in practice

**Parent Component**

```
<div style="display:table;">
  <div style="display: table-header-group; font-weight:bold;">
    <div style="display:table-cell;padding 3px 10px;">Column A</div>
    <div style="display:table-cell;padding 3px 10px;">Column B</div>
    <div style="display:table-cell; padding 3px 10px;">Column C</div>
  </div>
  <div style="display:table-row-group">
    <childselector [childinformation]="informationarray"></childselector>
  </div>

  </div>
```

**Child Component**

```
<div style="display: table-row;">
      <div style="display:table-cell; padding 3px 10px;">{{Content A}}</div>
      <div style="display:table-cell; padding 3px 10px;">{{Content B}}</div>
      <div style="display:table-cell; padding 3px 10px;">{{Content C}}</div>
    </div>
<ng-container *ngIf="child.informationarray.length>0">
          <childselector [childinformation]="child.informationarray"></childselector>
        </ng-container
```

**Note: The Above was pseudo code, but I hope you can get the idea. The following CSS problem emerges -- instead of the table appearing like this:

```
|Column A    |Column B     |Column C|
......................................
|Row1-A      |Row1-B       |Row1-C  |
......................................
|SubRow1-A   |SubRow1-B    |SubRow1-C|
```

It looks like this:

```
|Column A                            |Column B     |Column C|
.............................................................
|Row1-A                              |Row1-B       |Row1-C  |
.............................................................
|SubRow1-A   |SubRow1-B    |SubRow1-C|             |
```

I created a plunkr to better illustrate the problem here:

https://embed.plnkr.co/gVEEJa06eJPd0rvelFdv/

Greatly appreciate any help with this.

Answer (score 1):

Issue here is the `subrow` component gets wrapped in the DOM (`<subrow>[...]</subrow>`), then you loose the display table feature on that.

Solution here would be using attribute selectors

```
@Component({
  selector: '[subrow]'
  ...
})
```

and then use it like

`<div style="display: table-row;" subrow></div>` instead `<subrow></subrow>`

see: https://plnkr.co/edit/x8grzu5XWMcGA96g0HA9

Comment: While this does work for the plunkr that I supplied, it does not work as solution to the larger problem I am having

Essentially I have a large nested JSON object that I am trying to recursively display in a table , but as you suggested I am having trouble finding out how to get around the selectors even with using attribute selectors.

Comment: Basically, if I have a large nested JSON, and the parent table has this information: 

    <div class="dTableBody" app-pgridrow [pgrid]="portfolioitems" >
      
    </div>


 and the child object has this information : 
<ng-container *ngFor  -- all the items for that level of json> 
  <div class=TableRow>
     <div class= TableCell>
      ......
   </div>
    
 now how do I get the row to call itself without inserting markup that breaks the table
<ng-container>

Comment: Can you place the *ngFor inside the `TableRow` instead? like:  `<div class=TableRow *ngFor="[ ... ]">`. or it will break your logic? can you make a plunkr with your example?